# Count and list out unique combination by group

Tags: t-sql

I am wanting to derive a SQL that can bring me the following result, but I just can't seem to get my head around this particular scenario.

I want to see how many individual combination of ROLE-combination by USER there are, and report the count and list out role-names.

Here is the example table:

```
USER ROLE
AAA  Report
AAA  Enquiry
AAA  Manager
BBB  Report
BBB  Enquiry
BBB  Manager
CCC  Enquiry
CCC  Report
DDD  Report
EEE  Report
EEE  Enquiry
EEE  Admin
FFF  Report
FFF  Enquiry
GGG  Report
GGG  Enquiry
GGG  Manager
GGG  PAYROLL
HHH  Report
III  Report
III  Enquiry
```

There are AAA, and BBB with role combination of "Report-Enquiry-Manager", therefore count of 2 recored.

There is only CCC with Enquiry-Report.

There are DDD and HHH with role of Report.

Therefore, the desired output would be

```
COUNT   ROLE-COMBINATION
2       Report-Enquiry-Manager
3       Enquiry-Report
2       Report
1       Report-Enquiry-Admin
1       Report-Enquiry-Manager-PAYROLL
```

Could someone point me to the right direction please.

Thanks heaps,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user `GROUP BY` to get Count and use `STUFF` to get `-` separated role values.

```
create table test
(
    [USER] varchar(10)
    ,[Role] varchar(100)
)
insert into test values
('AAA','Report')
,('AAA','Enquiry')
,('AAA','Manager')
,('BBB','Report')
,('BBB','Enquiry')
,('BBB','Manager')
,('CCC','Enquiry')
,('CCC','Report')
,('DDD','Report')
,('EEE','Report')
,('EEE','Enquiry')
,('EEE','Admin')
,('FFF','Report')
,('FFF','Enquiry')
,('GGG','Report')
,('GGG','Enquiry')
,('GGG','Manager')
,('GGG','PAYROLL')
,('HHH','Report')
,('III','Report')
,('III','Enquiry')


select COunt(1) as [COUNT], [Role-Combination] from 
(

select Count(1) as [Count], t.[User]
,STUFF((SELECT 
                        '-' + cm.[role] AS [text()]
                    FROM 
                    test cm
                    WHERE
                    cm.[user] = t.[user]
                    order by [role] desc
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        , root('user'), TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '' )AS [Role-Combination]
from test t
GROUP BY t.[User]

) result
group by result.[Role-Combination]

DROP TABLE test
```

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed.What is the rule to order your `Role-Combination`? or is  `Report-Enquiry` same as `Enquiry-Report`?

Comment: Thanks @AB_87,  Report-Enquiry same as Enquiry-Report :D

Comment: @reilic Then the query I provided should work for you.

Comment: Yes indeed. I learnt something new today. STUFF, never even came across this before. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @USER TABLE 
(
    xUSER VARCHAR(30),
    xROLE VARCHAR(30)
)
INSERT INTO @USER (xUSER,xROLE)
VALUES
('AAA','Report'),
('AAA','Enquiry'),
('AAA','Manager'),
('BBB','Report'),
('BBB','Enquiry'),
('BBB','Manager'),
('CCC','Enquiry'),
('CCC','Report'),
('DDD','Report'),
('EEE','Report'),
('EEE','Enquiry'),
('EEE','Admin'),
('FFF','Report'),
('FFF','Enquiry'),
('GGG','Report'),
('GGG','Enquiry'),
('GGG','Manager'),
('GGG','PAYROLL'),
('HHH','Report'),
('III','Report'),
('III','Enquiry')

; WITH x AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        xUSER,
        STUFF((
            SELECT '- ' + xRole
            FROM @User
            WHERE xUser = a.xUSer           
            ORDER BY xRole
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 1, 1, '') Groups
    FROM @User a
)
SELECT 
    [Cnt] = COUNT(xUser),   Groups as [Role-Cmbine]
FROM x
GROUP BY Groups
ORDER BY [Cnt] DESC
```